# Continue after MouseEvent (Click) in C#

Tags: c#, mouseevent, mouselistener, mouseup

i want my application to wait for a mouseclick and then continue. 
My Application is basically this:

```
static class SomeClass {
   bool clicked = false;
   //some Code....

   //activate MouseUp Event & wait for mouse click
   _app.Application.MouseUp += MouseEventOnShape;

   //continue with the filled list after mouse click happened
   if(clicked) {
      //do something with list
   }
}
```

My MouseEvent looks like this:

```
private static void MouseEventOnShape(int button, int keybuttonstate, double 
x, double y, ref bool canceldefault) {
   clicked = true;
   // some code to do and fill a list

}
```

However the application does not wait for the mouseclick to set the bool to true.

Can anyone help?

Comment: It's a little hard to tell from that little peace of code. But I guess you actually want to do that `//do something with list` _inside_ the `MouseEventOnShape` method, so it's executed _when the mouse click appears_ (precisily when the mouse button is released again, as you registered the `MouseUp` event)

Comment: What kind of application is this?

Comment: @RenéVogt What i want to do is to fill a list with visio shapes based on their position! I have the code for filling the list and i want to fill it when the mouse is clicked, so in the `MouseEventOnShape`. I need this filled list in `SomeClass` to process it there.

Comment: @Idle_Mind it is an Office Add-In for Visio

Answer (score 0):

If you want some class (actually it's method) to wait for a click, you may want to use `ManualResetEvent` which will pause method execution until it gets click. But here, you have to care about blocking UI thread. Try call `WaitForClick` method as is. If your app completely freezes, you have to call it in another way, for example in background thread.

See example:

```
private ManualResetEvent _waiter = new ManualResetEvent(false);

private void OnApplicationClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _waiter.Set();
}

private void WaitForClick()
{
    _app.Application.Click += OnApplicationClick;
    _waiter.WaitOne();
    // do something after click
}
```

**EDIT:** You may fill your list directly in event handler:

```
private void OnMouseUp(...)
{
    Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        // fill your list here
    }));
}

private void RegisterListener()
{
    _app.Application.MouseUp += OnMouseUp;
}
```

Comment: @RenéVogt but he explained it right, i want the method of `SomeClass` to wait until the mouse was clicked & the list is filled. Don't know whether this code works?!

Comment: @dnks23 I wrote that comment before the "answer was completely rewrit[ten]"

Comment: @RenéVogt ooh ok. so i will try this

Comment: my `_app.Application` don't has a `Click` i only can use `MouseUp` as above. `MouseUp` does need the `MouseEventOnShape` -method as above. If i try it like @opewix solution my application thread gets blocked.

Comment: @RenéVogt thank you for grammar check, I've removed that note

Comment: @dnks23 can you fill your list inside MouseUp event handler instead of waiting for it in a method?

Comment: @opewix yes should work. do you have a example for that?

Comment: @dnks23 see my edit for example. `Invoke` is a method `Control` class. It will allow you to update your UI from separate thread

Comment: @opewix so i don't need the `_waiter` anymore?

Comment: @dnks23 yes you don't need it if you can fill your list in event handler

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149875/discussion-between-opewix-and-dnks23).